# Pre-commit error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I think this is a Windows/WSL/Linux issue. anyone able to assist as when i install pre-commit and try to commit i get the error:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory
```

all software and actions are taken on `wsl2` or vscode terminal (which connects to wsl)

- `git clone` (I can commit, branch etc fine from vscode)
- `pre-commit run -a` runs succesfully
- `pre-commit install` (says setup is successful)
- `python3` is installed and working on `wsl`

looking in the `.git` i can see the hooks folder and the pre-commit file which is below:

```
#!/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/pre-commit/libexec/bin/python3
# File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com
# ID: 138fd403232d2ddd5efb44317e38bf03
import os
import sys

# we try our best, but the shebang of this script is difficult to determine:
# - macos doesn't ship with python3
# - windows executables are almost always `python.exe`
# therefore we continue to support python2 for this small script
if sys.version_info < (3, 3):
    from distutils.spawn import find_executable as which
else:
    from shutil import which

# work around https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/30445
os.environ.pop('__PYVENV_LAUNCHER__', None)

# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON = '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/pre-commit/libexec/bin/python3'
ARGS = ['hook-impl', '--config=.pre-commit-config.yaml', '--hook-type=pre-commit']
# end templated
ARGS.extend(('--hook-dir', os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
ARGS.append('--')
ARGS.extend(sys.argv[1:])

DNE = '`pre-commit` not found.  Did you forget to activate your virtualenv?'
if os.access(INSTALL_PYTHON, os.X_OK):
    CMD = [INSTALL_PYTHON, '-mpre_commit']
elif which('pre-commit'):
    CMD = ['pre-commit']
else:
    raise SystemExit(DNE)

CMD.extend(ARGS)
if sys.platform == 'win32':  # https://bugs.python.org/issue19124
    import subprocess

    if sys.version_info < (3, 7):  # https://bugs.python.org/issue25942
        raise SystemExit(subprocess.Popen(CMD).wait())
    else:
        raise SystemExit(subprocess.call(CMD))
else:
    os.execvp(CMD[0], CMD)
```

### UPDATE

Its a VSCode issue.. doing a manual vscode commit uses windows git and so looks for python3 in windows. If i use the wsl terminal and run the git commands they work and use `pre-commit`

Guess my question is, is there a way to use vscode git with wsl or does it have to use windows?

Comment: that shebang is only going to be valid *inside* your WSL instance -- you must be committing outside of WSL ? - it'd be impossible to support install on one OS and then run on another - the pre-commit author

Comment: what is this line for `#!/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/pre-commit/libexec/bin/python3`

Answer (score 1):

@Staggerlee011, looking at your script, it seems that you are missing the `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script. Adding this to my pre-commit script, saving, and running a commit was successful. To be honest, I did not know that could be the solution, because it looks like a comment, but it did. Thinking about it though, it seems that **Git** recognizes it, and processes it.

Answer (score 0):

OK!

So this is purely a vscode / wsl integration issue and nothing to do with `pre-commit`.

Its caused by vscode using windows git, While i installed pre-commit and all the tools for it on `wsl`.

So you can make VSCode use WSL git repos and apps via using the extension: `wsl - remote`

you might be able to also update the `settings.json` with `git.path:`  but i havent tested that!